# android switch gradually between two colored texts

Tags: android, alpha-transparency, textcolor

I have a vertical seek bar and two textviews. One textview is transparent and the other textview is set right on top of the other one. When dragging the thumb of the seek bar the transparent textview comes into view and the other textview turns transparent gradually (getting the effect that the text is switching gradually). Problem is that this works fine when the text is black, but I need to color every two letters of every word in a different color. I have tried coloring the text using setText(Html.fromHtml() and with SpannableString. The coloring in both cases works fine but i can't seem to make the switch between texts work, any ideas?

this is how it works when the text is black:

```
VerticalSeekBar vSeekBar2 = (VerticalSeekBar)findViewById(R.id.SeekBar02);
vSeekBar2.setMax(255);
vSeekBar2.setProgress(255);
vSeekBar2.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new VerticalSeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(VerticalSeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(VerticalSeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(VerticalSeekBar seekBar, int progress,
        boolean fromUser) {
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textvu)).setTextColor(Color.argb(progress, 0, 0, 0));
    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.textvu2)).setTextColor(Color.argb((255-progress), 0, 0, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Android 3.0+, then use the `setAlpha()` property on the `View` rather than changing the text color.  This uses floating points rather than integer from 0 (transparent) to 1.0 (full).  This has the advantage in that you can change the entire TextView rather than just the Text.

If using Android 2.3 or lower, then you can use `getPaint()` on the `TextView`.  Then apply `setAlpha()` on the given `Paint` object.  This will use integers between 0 (transparent) to 255 (full).  This will not effect other properties of the `TextView` like background.

Comment: DeeV, thanks for your quick response! i've tried to implement your solution for Android 2.3.6 but it didn't succeed. In each one of the textviews i have a word. Every two letters of every word are colored in one of two different colors (the word "apple" would be divided to "ap" (colored red) "pl" (colored green) "e"(colored red again). I've tried using getPaint() and applying setAlpha() but it didn't change the text's transperancy. I've also tried creating my own paint objects and that didn't work either. I've used Html to color the text, could that be the reason setAlpha does not work?